# How to call an ID for a DIV

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm a beginner so I hope this is not a stupid question.
I build a simple JS to refresh an image inside an iframe, when I use the 'id' of the iframe everything works, but when I change the 'id' to the 'id' of the DIV the iframe doesn't load again, how can I fix it?

```
<body>
<div id="333">
<iframe id="22" src='Image.jpg' width="200"></iframe>
</div>
</p>

<script>
  setInterval(refreshAd, 3000);
  function refreshAd() {
      var frame = document.getElementById("333");
      frame.src = frame.src;
}
      </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked console in your browser or in code redactor? There should be some errors, most likely because your DIV do not have **SRC attribute**, and which **iframe** have, so because of this line "frame.src = frame.src;", Javascript should console error and do not load your html

Also, to be sure, did some elements loaded or not, declare some variable and then check it by using "console.log(var)"
Beside of it, it do not matter which tag you are calling: HTML, BODY, H1, P... all of them you can call in same way, by id, by class, by tag...

Example on screenshot
[image]

1. Change `var frame = document.getElementById("333"); to var frame = document.getElementById("22");`
2. Delete `frame.src = frame.src;`

About 2-nd option, because `<div></div>`  do not have "src" attributes, you can not assign this value in your function, because its not right, you can do this to img or iframe , but not to DIV

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I change it? How can I make the whole  DIV load again?

Comment: You are welcome ) In your case you have 2 options, one moment will add this to main answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's happened because you are looking for a [div](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDivElement) element and try to change the property **src** that div doesn't have. Instead of it you need to looking for an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement) element.